# Adding text to a new line of existing file using Add-Content PowerShell

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-4.0

I am trying fetching content from a file using get-content and adding it to a existing file using add-content, but the issue is I am not able to add that content to new line. Can you please suggest on this?

Using below commands:

```
Get-content -Path $destRoot1 | Add-Content -Path $destRoot2
```

Comment: If the file doesn't already exist you'll need a slightly different syntax

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/add-content?view=powershell-7.1#example-5--create-a-new-file-and-copy-content

Comment: i guess you want to add specific lines of $destRoot1 and app end to $destRoot2?

Comment: @FletcherF1  I want to append all the lines from $destRoot1 to $destRoot2 but from the second line and it should also override previous content from second line to end of the file. First line should remain constant.

Comment: @DavidMartin File exists already as I just need to override the content from line number 2. first line is constant.

Comment: Run `"" |Add-Content ...` before appending the other file?

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen It not working giving error : 
Get-Content : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument ' '

Comment: @Divya You still need to supply the path to the file: `""| Add-Content -Path $destRoot2`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved it by using below trick:

```
1.Add-Content -Path $destRoot2 "`n" 
##### I am adding new line character to existing file #####
2.Get-content -Path $destRoot1 | Add-Content -Path $destRoot2 -Encoding UTF8
##### Appending data from $destRoot1 to $destRoot2 #####
3.((Get-Content -Path $destRoot2) -notmatch '^\s*$' )| Select-Object -Unique | Set-Content -Path $destRoot2 -Encoding UTF8 
##### Using -notmatch '^\s*$' removing the blank line which I have added at line number 1 #####
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the content to the destination file path and not add content. Refer the change below:

```
$destRoot1 = "C:\File\path1.txt"
$destRoot2 = "C:\destination\path\of\the\file.txt"
Get-content -Path $destRoot1 |Set-Content -Path $destRoot2 -Force
```

Comment: I don't want set it as I need to append it from second line. $$destRoot2 contains the headers which I don't want to remove and need to add the data after the header from second line

Comment: @Divya:  Ya, then just simply use -Append to add lines to the existing file.